# Using laplacian transform to derive a general solution to the quantum harmonic oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, laplace-transform

I'm unhappy with the often used approach of guessing the form of the solution and working from there. In the case of the quantum harmonic oscillator, once the form
\begin{equation}\frac{d^2 \psi(x)}{dx^2}+(\frac{2E}{\hbar^2}-\frac{m^2 \omega^2}{\hbar^2}x^2)\psi(x)=0\end{equation}
is arrived at, the substitution
\begin{equation} y(x)=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}x\end{equation}
is made, followed by some simple calculus, which is then followed by the assumption
\begin{equation}\frac{2E}{\hbar\omega}<<y^2.\end{equation}

We then have
\begin{equation}\frac{d^2 \psi(y)}{dy^2}-y^2\psi(y)=0.\end{equation}

From here everyone "guesses" the form (we already know it, really) but I would like to try to solve this equation using the laplacian transform to arrive at the known general solution, which after this step would likely involve power series.

I've seen a solution using laplacian transforms here http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0143-0807/34/1/199 but it it not carried out at the step I wish to carry out the procedure.

My attempt at transforming the ODE gives
\begin{equation}s^2 Y(s)-s\psi(0)-\psi'(0)-Y''(s)=0.\end{equation}
From here I have no idea what to do. I have tried using general intial conditions, such as \begin{equation}\psi(0)=a, \psi'(0)=b; a,b\equiv const.\end{equation}

I don't know what to do with this equation after this, if this is even correct and if it is, whether this is a viable path to the well known general solution of the quantum harmonic oscillator.

Help please!

Comment: The problem is that the solutions *isn't* in some sense known.  Or rather, the solution to that differential equation cannot be written in terms of elementary functions.  In fact, the general solution to the second differential equation is the product of a Gaussian with a Hermite function one hand, and the product of a "growing Gaussian" with a complex Hermite function on the other.  The Hermite functions are not elementary, and hence we can't just get the solution... If you look in a QM textbook, you'll see that the approximate equation is only *approximately* solved, by a Gaussian.

Comment: Even in that paper, they don't apply the Laplace transform to the equation that you're trying to solve.  In fact, they strip of the Gaussian behavior *first* before taking a Laplace transform, so they aren't using that to find the Gaussian behavior.  Indeed, you can see why by your transformation of the equation: it is basically the *same equation*, other than the extra factors evaluated at 0.  This is in fact a feature of the harmonic oscillator: it looks the same when taking a Fourier transform (and so taking a Laplace transform will do something similar).

Comment: *However*, if you're interested, I can walk you through an alternative method that uses the asymptotic analysis and the method of dominant balance to derive the leading Gaussian behavior.  It still requires a guess of a sort, though, so I don't know if that's what you want.

Comment: @march I was originally using this http://physics.gmu.edu/~dmaria/590%20Web%20Page/public_html/qm_topics/harmonic/ as my guide and when I came to the point about guessing the form of the solution, I got annoyed at having to yet again guess.

I've gone through the textbook Intro to QM by A.C. Phillips recently and wanted to delve a bit deeper into the maths.

I also know, that the authors of that paper aren't stripping the gaussian behaviour using the laplacian transform but since I know other differential equations can be solved using the transform, I thought it could also be applied here.

Comment: Guessing is the name of the game, though. Every method of solving a differential equation involves either a guess or a transformation to a new differential equation that allows you to guess the solution. Solving partial differential equations sometimes involves guessing that the solution is separable. Ordinary differential equations can be solved by guessing that the solution is a Taylor series. Methods like dominant balance involve a guess of a transformation $\psi=e^s$, for instance. There's little getting around this.

Comment: @march I was suspecting, that this is the case, especially after I asked a friend of mine, who is surrounded every day by differential equations of all sorts. He told me, he also didn't like the guessing game when we were both at uni but that it is his go-to approach now....

Answer (score 0):

The Laplace transform is not very natural as it is rather designed to analyse causal signals (ie having a support of the positive numbers). At the very least, a Fourier transform would be more relevant. It has the added benefit of being physically transparent: you are looking at the problem in the momentum basis. However, the result is the same as in the Laplace transform: the new equation is strictly identical, so there is no simplification. I don’t have access to the paper you linked, so I can’t explain how the authors managed to circumvent this difficulty.

This isn’t so surprising when you think about it; the quadratic potential isn’t invariant by translation, so you shouldn’t expect these approaches to drastically simplify the problem. Actually, it turns out that the eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator are precisely eigenvectors of the Fourier transform, so this explains why you retrieve exactly the same equation after a Fourier transform.

Instead of blindly guessing the solution though, the easiest method is to find analytic solutions and expand the Taylor series about $0$. The coefficients will satisfy a simple induction formula which you can easily solve.  This is typically how you calculate the ground state without having to appeal to parachuted solutions. You’ll find this method when solving the Colomb potential also.

Hope this helps and tell me if something’s not clear.

Comment: [Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.7011.pdf) is the ArXiv link.  They do not use the Laplace transform to approximately solve the differential equation to derive the Gaussian part of the wave function. In the paper, that happens *before* they apply the Laplace transform, so OP is trying to do something the authors of the paper did *not*. Also, per your 3rd paragraph: the power series solution for the SHO happens *after* the asymptotic Gaussian behavior has been peeled off.  Only then will we get a simple recursion formula for the coefficients. But the question is about the peeling-off part.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Indeed I understand the question better now, my bad. Please disregard my answer.